# How to show $\hat {\partial_i u_j} = \frac{\xi_i \xi_k}{|\xi|^2} \hat {\omega_{kj}}$ for $i,j=1,2,3,...,n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Consider $u \in (L^2 (\mathbb R^n))^n$, i.e. $u$ is a vector-valued function. Suppose $\omega_{ij} = \partial_i u_j - \partial_j u_i$ for $i,j=1,2,3,...,n$. How to show $\hat {\partial_i u_j} = \frac{\xi_i \xi_k}{|\xi|^2} \hat {\omega_{kj}}$ for $i,j=1,2,3,...,n$?
Here, the $\hat{}$ means the Fourier transform.

Comment: Where are you blocked ? Have you tried to prove the relationship for $n=2$, $n=3$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I actually tried but it seems I don't know where to start.